# Click event in for loop | i value is always the last value

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am a CasperJS beginner.

I want to loop through all the li s of an ul and click on each li. When clicked on li, a modal popups up and am saving the modal data. But the value of 'i' inside the loop is always the end value. 
I have 5 lis in the ul.
The following loop always clicks on the 5th li 5 times and is saving the modal data 5 times when 5th li is clicked.

```
casper.then(function() {
  a = lis.length;
  this.echo(a + ' lis found');
  for(var i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
    this.echo(i + ' now');
    this.click('.hello:nth-child('+ i +')' );
    casper.waitUntilVisible('.modal__content ', function() {
      console.log('Open Modal');
      links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
    });
  }
});
```

I googled and found out we should  wrap the assignment of the event listener in a closure. But this doesn't echo anything.

```
casper.then(function() {
  a = lis.length;
  this.echo(a + ' lis found');
  for(var i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
    (function(i){  // Added this line
      this.echo(i + ' now');
      this.click('.hello:nth-child('+ i +')' );
      casper.waitUntilVisible('.modal__content ', function() {
        console.log('Open Modal');
        links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
      });
    })(i); // Added this line
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing click to thenClick solved the problem :)

```
casper.then(function() {
  a = lis.length;
  this.echo(a + ' lis found');
  for(var i = 1; i <= a; i++ ) {
    this.echo(i + ' now');
    this.thenClick('.hello:nth-child('+ i +')' ); // Changed to thenClick from click
    casper.waitUntilVisible('.modal__content ', function() {
      console.log('Open Modal');
      links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
    });
  }
});
```